# sbt multimodule project importing trait from another module

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an sbt project with multiple modules, each with their own `build.sbt` file.

In the root project, I have the following:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
    organization := "com.game.scala",
    sourcesInBase := false,
    fork in run := true,
    scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
)

lazy val common = project.settings(commonSettings)

lazy val original = project.settings(commonSettings).dependsOn(common)

lazy val functional = project.settings(commonSettings).dependsOn(common)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(original, functional)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```

The build.sbt in all the submodules are pretty much the same:

```
lazy val module = (project in file("."))

  .settings(
    name := "Game subpart",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  )
```

And the layout of the project looks something like:

```
root
|__ common
|__ original
|__ functional
```

The problem is that from within the `functional` module, if I try importing a trait declared in `common` module, I get an error that it is not available:

> Error:(1, 12) object game is not a member of package com
>
> import com.game.scala

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you never compiled your `common` project. The `dependsOn` method only add a dependency to the other project, but do no action on it, unless explicitly asked to. If you want your dependency to be re-compiled whenever the `functional` module is compiled, you should do both `dependsOn(common)` and `aggregate(common)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not fix the problem. Anyways sbt has given me enough headache, I've decided to switch to gradle